# How to send e-mails automatically from a sheet as it updated?

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I posted this question on Google Sheets forum and was directed here for help.
*Please note that I am not a coder, I've just started working with things like this.

I've created a workbook with 3 pages. It's connected to a form, so as people submit their reviews the answers are collected on the first sheet, calculated on the second sheet, and any submission with an overall score higher than 3.9 has the email address moved to the third sheet where it will be sent a follow-up email.

Here is a link to a copy of the sheet: 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15p7_M4guRWCVHG-acRAheAROmh9t4wk3GWD_x0_rl90/edit?usp=sharing

It all works except the last page: I cannot figure out how to get the emails to send automatically as the sheet is updated. I've set the trigger to have it run when the sheet is updated, but to no avail - I have to manually go in and click the "Run" button to have the emails sent. (When I do, it pops up 'Failed to sent email: no recipient (line 21, file "Code")' but the emails are successfully delivered anyway.)

The formula I am using is this: (I have also tried swapping "sendEmails2" with "autoResponder" but that didn't change anything either.) Can anyone tell me what is wrong with it? Or is there a better way to automatically send the e-mails?

```
// This constant is written in column C for rows for which an email
// has been sent successfully.
var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT";

function sendEmails2() {
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
   var numRows = 20000;   // Number of rows to process
   // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 3)
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0];  // First column
    var message = row[1];       // Second column
    var emailSent = row[2];     // Third column
    if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) {  // Prevents sending duplicates
      var subject = "Sending emails from a Spreadsheet";
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 3).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is  
interrupted
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Trying send emails by using the spreadsheets onFormSubmit event.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
function sendEmails2(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Automatic Emails');
  var rg=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow(), 3);
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  for (var i=0;i<vA.length;i++){
    var emailAddress = vA[i][0];
    var message = vA[i][1];       
    var emailSent = vA[i][2];     
    var subject = "Sending emails from a Spreadsheet";
    if(emailSent != 'EMAIL_SENT'){
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      sh.getRange(2 + i,3).setValue('EMAIL_SENT');
    }
  }
}
```

Don't forget the onFormSubmit:

[image]